# Why on earth isn't this Javascript - SVG CSS-manipulation working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, svg

I'm snapping soonish (*questioners note*)

This is the SVG-image I'm using: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:World98.svg&page=1

It's a free *public domain* - global map made in SVG where (almost) every country has been surrounded by their respective borders.

**Don't go there yet! You don't have to look for it right away.**

I have something else to tell you first.

Here is the relevant part of the image:
(**edit**) *Spain is the country I'm trying to manipulate in both examples*

```
<g
   id="gESP">
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M472.55,197.77 472.27,198.22 471.8,197.9 472.55,197.77Z"
     id="polyF1S67P1" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M479.45,196.82 479.35,197.75 478.75,197.9 478.33,197.55 478.67,196.8 479.45,196.82Z"
     id="polyF1S67P2" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M474.5,197.17 474.1,196.9 474.3,196.67 474.72,196.92 474.5,197.17Z"
     id="polyF1S67P3" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M476.85,196.17 475.95,197.22 475.27,196.3 477.45,195.62 476.85,196.17Z"
     id="polyF1S67P4" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M482.8,196.77 481.97,196.95 482.7,196.62 483.33,195.27 483.75,195.17 483.55,196.52 482.8,196.77Z"
     id="polyF1S67P5" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M472.7,195.88 472.22,195.12 472.42,194.9 473,195.22 472.7,195.88Z"
     id="polyF1S67P6" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M484.12,194.7 483.72,194.82 483.92,194.3 484.95,193.9 484.8,194.45 484.12,194.7Z"
     id="polyF1S67P7" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M526.65,167.6 526.12,167.47 526.65,167.6Z"
     id="polyF1S67P8" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M526.25,166.9 525.62,166.95 525.97,166.45 526.72,166.42 526.25,166.9Z"
     id="polyF1S67P9" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M530.97,164.47 531.85,164.75 530.77,165.85 529.72,165.17 528.82,165.1 530.3,164.15 531.12,164 530.97,164.47Z"
     id="polyF1S67P10" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M534.15,164.35 532.97,164.02 532.95,163.72 533.97,163.8 534.15,164.35Z"
     id="polyF1S67P11" />
  <path
     class="region"
     d="M500.85,153.45 502.62,154.02 506,153.77 509.67,154.4 512.23,154.12 515.75,154.65 517.25,154.42 518.32,154.9 518.17,155.42 518.62,155.27 520.6,156.12 523.67,156.45 524.35,156.02 525.97,156.42 526.38,157.15 529.6,157.4 530.47,157.05 531.43,157.55 531.02,157.62 531.25,158.5 530.57,159 528.02,160.32 525.1,160.95 524.22,161.62 524.62,162 523.9,162.2 521.32,165.22 521.67,166.5 522.8,167.35 520.8,168.57 519.97,170.1 520.1,170.57 518.55,170.67 517.67,171.15 516.15,172.95 515.42,172.7 514.5,173.02 510.1,173.02 509.25,173.6 507.88,173.82 506.6,174.95 505.45,174.5 504.5,173.25 504.97,172.47 504.47,172.7 503.17,171.45 501.65,171.72 501.4,170.77 502.9,168.92 502.5,168.95 501.82,168.17 502.8,166.52 501.3,164.85 502.7,164.7 503.07,163.85 502.7,163.42 503.32,162.95 503.02,161.02 504.9,159.45 504.05,159.25 503.85,158.5 499.6,158.88 499.27,157.97 497.65,158.55 497.55,158.05 498.1,157.57 497.75,157.55 497.8,156.67 497.15,156.7 497.42,156.12 496.57,155.62 496.75,155.07 497.57,154.65 499.02,154.47 499.3,153.95 500.85,153.45Z"
     id="polyF1S67P12" />
</g>
```

What I want to do, is to fill the country in red with Javascript.

I've tried this:

**Attempt #1** - *no success*

```
function selectedCountryChanged(id) {
    var tmp = $("#selectedCountry").find("option:selected");
    var val = tmp.data('alpha');

    console.log('val'); // shows ESP in console

    for (var s in a.style) {
        console.log(s); // shows correctly all style properties in console
    }
        var a = document.getElementById("g"+val);
    a.style.fill = '#ffff00';
    console.log(a.style.fill); // shows rgb(255, 0, 0) in console
}
```

**Attempt #2** - *no success*

```
function selectedCountryChanged(id) {
    var tmp = $("#selectedCountry").find("option:selected");
    var val = tmp.data('alpha');
    var a = document.getElementById("g"+val);
    console.log(val); // shows ESP in console
    for(var s in a.style) {
        console.log(s); // shows all css-properties correctly
    }
    console.log(id + " " + val);

    a.setAttribute("style", "fill: #ff0000");
    console.log(a.style.getPropertyValue("fill")); // shows rgb(255, 0, 0) in console
}
```

Even if all the debug information shows everything is okay, there must be a reson why this damn thing  doesn't fill with red? If I do it manually by forking the css-part in SVG-file, it shows okay.

I've included only the most relevant parts of the code (IMHO). I'll post more upon request.

**EDIT:** Tested with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. Both fail.

**EDIT #2:** In neither approach, Firebug nor Javascript console (in Chrome) gave no errors.

---

**EDIT:**

Both, @Bill in his comment and @Simon Boudrias in his answer, were pointing out the problem just as it was.

Many of the child paths of the main element were filled with white and needed to be overrided. The solution was finally trivial.

**The Solution**

```
function selectedCountryChanged(id) {
    // use the selection id to get alpha3-country identifier
    var tmp = $("#selectedCountry").find("option:selected");
    var val = tmp.data('alpha');
    // Get the style - element defined in SVG
    var a = document.getElementById("mapStyle");
    // By assigning the * as class name, we quarantee
    // that all the children are filled with red as well
    var newFill = "#g"+val+" * { fill: red; }";
    // If prevSelectedCountry is set, remove the red filling by
    // setting it white
    if (window.prevSelectedCountry != undefined) {
        $(a).append(window.prevSelectedCountry);
    }
    // Add this country to prevSelectedCountry
    window.prevSelectedCountry = "#g"+val+" * { fill: white; }";
    // Fill this country with red
    $(a).append(newFill);
}
```

Comment: Is there a `fill` defined within the SVG file on the `paths`? If so, that fill would take precedence over a fill color applied to the group.

Comment: @Bill Well, not in country itself but in the svg-file, yes, in several places. If you have time, please take a glance at the original svg-image I linked on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Bill Would this mean that my manual modifications (like I said, this works when I alter the svg-file directly) always takes priority over Javascript-access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I'm looking at the .svg images, I see that most of the `<path>` elements have a `fill` attributes set to white. So, you'll need to overwrite or delete this property first.

As you're selecting a group `<g>` element. So, in order to make the fill property or style attribute work on it's children `<path>` you need to clear or change their own fill attributes.

So, you can test this: (may need some tweek depending of what are the values of some variables you use)

```
function selectedCountryChanged(id) {
    var tmp = $("#selectedCountry").find("option:selected");
    var val = tmp.data('alpha');
    var paths = $("#g" + val).find('path');

    paths.attr("fill", "#ff0000");
}
```

Comment: Did exactly what you suggested but nothing turned to red. However I believe that you and Bill might be on the right tracks as both of you noticed (or guessed) the same possible reason. I'll take this into greater consideration tomorrow. I've got to take a nap. I haven't slept in 28 hrs. I really like to crack these babies :D

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I was able to solve it. I added by solution into the question. For telling me where to find the answer, I'm accepting yours :)